# How to convert a Systemd service to OpenRC?

Tags: linux, init

I want to add a service to my Artix linux system, which is a Arch Linux drivate with OpenRC as init system.

Consider the systemd service

```
[Unit]
Description=sets battery thresholds

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/usr/bin/tpacpi-bat -s ST 0 40
ExecStart=/usr/bin/tpacpi-bat -s SP 0 80
ExecStop=/usr/bin/tpacpi-bat -s ST 0 0
ExecStop=/usr/bin/tpacpi-bat -s SP 0 0

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

how do I convert this into openrc and should it placed so that can add it via `rc-service {service-name} start`?

Answer (score 1):

```
% cat systemd.service
[Unit]
Description=sets battery thresholds
[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/usr/bin/tpacpi-bat -s ST 0 40
ExecStart=/usr/bin/tpacpi-bat -s SP 0 80
ExecStop=/usr/bin/tpacpi-bat -s ST 0 0
ExecStop=/usr/bin/tpacpi-bat -s SP 0 0    
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

% initify.pl systemd.service

% cat systemd
#!/sbin/openrc-run
command=/usr/bin/tpacpi-bat
command_args="-s ST 0 40"
pidfile=
name="systemd"
description="sets battery thresholds"
```

The shebang is for Gentoo; in Artix it needs to be `#!/usr/bin/openrc-run`.

Comment: First of all, welcome to Super User! We are always glad to help, but you apparently have two Super User accounts: [this one](https://superuser.com/users/926266/nous) and [this one](https://superuser.com/users/926282/nous). Please take the time to utilize the following Help Center tutorial and ask the Super User staff to merge your accounts: [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts)

Answer (score 1):

Recently, a dedicated online service has been set up for converting systemd service files to OpenRC init scripts: http://openrc.run/

Answer (score 0):

There's a user-contributed script that does basic systemd.service to openrc initscript conversion: https://forum.artixlinux.org/index.php/topic,276.0.html

Comment: Can you elaborate on this a little more?